# ERROR: Device or resource busy, when running dockerfile or creating container on RedHat 6.8

Tags: docker

I am trying to build dockerfile and i am getting following error.

```
"ERROR: Device or resource busy"

Same error i am getting when i try to create a container using command.

docker run -it 80e46367f846 /bin/bash
"error response from daemon cannot start container xxxxxxxx device or resource busy"
```

Docker version:

Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d/1.7.1

Comment: Have you had any success at all running docker on RHEL 6.8? Because from docker website it says docker requires RHEL 7 and above.

Comment: Are you using mounted disk?

Comment: @Lukman 1.7.1 was the last version supported on RHEL6, so this is legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lukman's right. Docker is not compatible with Redhat 6.x. Similary on centos 6.x also it has some issues. So Redhat 7.x is recommended.